# Showing these two selection principles are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology

I stumbled across a few articles about Selection Principles recently, and I'm slowly getting to know more about them as I go along. There's some background before I address the problem I ran into. $X$ is the space of reals, or a space homeomorphic to the reals.

- $\mathcal{U}$ is an $\omega$-cover of $X$ if each finite $F \subseteq X$ is contained in some $U \in \mathcal{U}$.
- $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$ if $\mathcal{U}$ is infinite and each $x \in X$ belongs to all but finitely many $U \in \mathcal{U}$.
- $X$ satisfies ${\Omega \choose \Gamma}$ if every $\omega$-cover contains a $\gamma$-subcover.
- $X$ satisfies $\mbox{ S}_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$ if for a sequence $\{\mathcal{U}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of open $\omega$-covers of $X$, there is a sequence $\{J_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $n$, $J_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$ and $\{J_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$.

There's an equivalence I keep running into, which has been stated without proof in pretty much every article I've read, so I decided to give it a go and see if I could prove it.

> X satisfies ${\Omega \choose \Gamma} \Leftrightarrow X \mbox{ satisfies }\mbox{ S}_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$.

The $\Leftarrow$ implication seemed straightforward, after I realized the sequence of open $\omega$-covers is allowed to be constant. I am having issues showing the $\Rightarrow$ implication.

I know I have to start with a sequence $\{\mathcal{U}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of open $\omega$-covers of $X$, but I'm not sure how to construct a sub-sequence of $\gamma$-covers of $X$ given that $X$ already satisfies ${\Omega \choose \Gamma}.$

Any solutions or hints/steps in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the paper (cited below) where the properties are introduced (before the notation was introduced in fact), where the left hand side is what the authors call $(\gamma)$ property, an the right hand side is the seemingly stronger $(\gamma')$ property.

See page 155/156 of [Some properties of $C(X)$ (I), by Gerlits and Nagy](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166864182900657/1-s2.0-0166864182900657-main.pdf?_tid=3cd2dffa-1884-11e6-8416-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1463086871_493375720604654f2de7581838ce90d1).

Note that $\underline{\operatorname{Lim}}(G_k) = X$ in their paper means that that the $G_k$ form a $\gamma$-cover of $X$.

The proof is not long but a bit involved. It does involve some manipulations of the original sequence of covers.